# How to type * character in nano?

Tags: linux, nano

I'm using Debian on an embedded ARM machine and using nano via PuTTY. I cannot figure out how to type the * character in nano. I also cannot figure out how to copy/paste a single character.

When I press * I get "File Name to Write:____" popup

Comment: I don't see any problem typing * in nano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The * character is typed in nano the same as any other keyboard character is typed. If that doesn't work, the keyboard combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> also enters the * character in nano.

To copy/paste a single character in nano, select a character and copy it, and then paste it into the open text file by selecting *Edit* -> *Paste* from the nano menu.

Comment: Pressing * in nano brings up "FIle Name to Write: ..." when I try it ? I'm using debian on an embedded ARM machine and using nano via putty if that helps.

Comment: Ok shift + 8 works. Ctrl + shift + 8 does not work though.

Comment: Initial state is already set to normal. Still have to use Shift + 8, either way not a big deal as I'm using SFTP to edit files now in a native editor which is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

[shift] + [ins] should work for paste. [ctrl] is usually the 'literal' input key.